# Loading paginated data into Grafana

Tags: grafana

I'm using one of the two datasources:

- marcusolsson-json-datasource
- yesoreyeram-infinity-datasource

Both can call HTTP API endpoints.
The problem is the endpoint returns paginated response (JSON)..

My panel will be a very simple table that just shows the endpoint's response to the query (HTTP Request).
What I want to achieve is making Grafana grab the paginated data..

Example: When I click on page 1 in table it make a request with `page_size=X&page_number=1` and so on.. Is that possible ?
If not possible.. what is the best thing to do here?
Should I use some kind of caching ? What cache suits best with my case and how to implement it?

I've been digging but I didn't really come to something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I could come up with is by using a dashboard variable..

- We create a variable that fills its value from a request to the endpoint and refreshes with the dashboard reload.
- We then use that as a dropdown variable starting from 1 to number of pages.. When a page number is selected, it makes a new request to the endpoint to load the data. (By including variable value as a query parameter.)

The thing with this approach is that it doesn't look nice like Grafana's table pagination pane. Instead, the user will have to choose a page number from a dropdown list.